# Duplicate Line Finder

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, file, edit-distance

I recently wrote a program that reads a plain text file, and compares every line and alerts you if any are similar, based on a float value that you pass in to a function.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class DuplicateLineFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final float SIMILARITY_RATE = 0.75f;

        String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/";
        String fileName = "lines.txt";
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation + fileName));

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size()-2; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < lines.size()-1; j++) {

                if (IsSimilar(lines.get(i), lines.get(j), SIMILARITY_RATE))
                    System.out.println("WARNING!\n " + lines.get(i) + "\n and \n" + lines.get(j) + "\n might be the same");
            }
        }

        file.close();
    }

    public static boolean IsSimilar(String line1, String line2, float percentSimilar) {
        int duplicateWordCount = 0;
        List<String> words1 = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(line1.split(" ")));
        List<String> words2 = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(line2.split(" ")));

        if (words1.size() >= words2.size()) {
            for (String word : words2) {
                if (words1.remove(word)) {
                    duplicateWordCount++;
                }
            }

            if (duplicateWordCount > (words2.size() * percentSimilar)) return true;
        }

        else if (words2.size() > words1.size()) {
            for (String word : words1) {
                if (words2.remove(word)) {
                    duplicateWordCount++;
                }
            }

            if (duplicateWordCount > (words1.size() * percentSimilar)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

It works well, and is customisable in case you want to make it more/less strict. I am wondering if there is a better way to do my if statements in the `IsSimilar` function, as without them it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. Yes but I don't know any of the new features

Comment: Even _if_ using Collection (`List`) was a good idea to implement `isSimilar()` (method members aren't usually capitalised): _What is_ the perceived advantage in changing roles depending on size? If one concern of yours is time complexity with large inputs, please state this in the question. (If you take a step back, you are computing the cardinal number of the intersection of two multisets.)

Comment: @greybeard the if statement for the size of the list was added because of an issue where if the second line of text was significantly shorter than the first it would generate false positives

Comment: (I can't see how - example?)

Answer (score 1):

To test case, you can use toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() methods in String to get case. Also using String, you can use the split(' ') method to get each word and compare them instead of using two lists. It would definately increase performance to some extent.

To get the contents a bit better, the new nio package was updated in java 8 and has methods like Files.readAllLines(Path p);, returning a List (a list of lines) instead of using the BufferedReader trick. You can also use readAllBytes(Path p); which will return a byte array, but it is much easier to use readAlLines for your case.

Other than that I don't think there is much to give you. You have done a good job.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

Your IsSimilar() function consists of the same code block, twice.  Anytime you have duplicate code you should usually either break it into it's own function or find another way of eliminating the duplication.

An example implementation removing duplicate code:

```
List<String> largeList;
List<String> smallList;

if(words1.size() > words2.size()) {
    largeList = words1;
    smallList = words2;
}
else {
    smallList = words1;
    largeList = words2;
}

for (String word : smallList) {
    if (largeList.remove(word)) {
        duplicateWordCount++;
    }
}

if (duplicateWordCount > (smallList.size() * percentSimilar)) return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not just this review, but your code starts with something I like: `Finder` reads way more positive than `Seeker, Hunter, LynchMob`…)

- Document your code - in the code.
  What *is* a line? When are *lines* similar?
- (Almost?) Good of you to declare `List<String> words` (for what is used, it might have been `Collection<String>`)
  (did you try to use the List provided by asList(), or ArrayList, instead? You might have provided comparative results.)
- don't do things over and again.
  Using String for *line*, you are splitting both lines on each and every comparison. Using String.split, the regular expression for splitting gets compiled time and again.
  With *line* not being String, you can try and find sub-quadratic solutions to whatever problem you are trying to solve…
- give non-legacy parts of the java runtime environment half a chance.
  like `Stream<String> java.nio.file.Files.lines(Path path)`
- document the purpose of the whole shebang - if it was to identify identical lines, motivate not just using an appropriate `Set.add()`.

Another Rendition:

```
/** find similar lines */
public class SimilarLineFinder {

 /** decide similarity to another Line */
    interface Line {
        boolean isSimilar(Line other, double param);
    }
 /** decide similarity to another Line based on words and counts */
    static class WordCountLine implements Line {
        final Pattern WORD_SEPARATOR = Pattern.compile("\\W+");
        String[]word;// there are fun games to play with char[][]
        int[]count;
        int words;
        public WordCountLine(String s) {
            Map<String, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();
            for (String word: WORD_SEPARATOR.split(s))
                counts.compute(word,
                    (k, v) -> null == v ? 1 : v + 1);
            counts.remove("");
            int n = counts.size();
            word = new String[n];
            count = new int[n];
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: counts.entrySet()) {
                word[--n] = e.getKey();//.toCharArray();
                int c = e.getValue();
                count[n] = c;
                words += c;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(word);
        }
    /** decide similarity based on {@code threshold}
     * and count of words common to both lines. */
        boolean similar(WordCountLine a, WordCountLine b,
                        double threshold) {
            WordCountLine s, l;
            if (a.words < b.words) {
                s = a; l = b;
            } else {
                s = b; l = a;
            }
            if (s.words <= 0)
                return l.words <= 0;
            int common = 0;
        intersect:
            for (int si = s.word.length, li = l.word.length ;
                0 <= --si && 0 <= --li ; ) {
                int cmp;
                String other = l.word[li];
                while ((cmp = s.word[si].compareTo(other)) < 0)
                    if (--si < 0)
                        break intersect;
                other = s.word[si];
                while (0 < cmp) {
                    if (--li < 0)
                        break intersect;
                    cmp = other.compareTo(l.word[li]);
                }
                if (0 == cmp)
                    common += Math.min(s.count[si], l.count[li]);
            }
            return common > s.words * threshold;
        }

        public boolean isSimilar(Line other, double threshold) {
            if (!(other instanceof WordCountLine))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "can only decide similaritiy with "
                    + getClass().getSimpleName() + ", not "
                    + ((null == other) ? "null"
                       : other.getClass().getName()));
            return similar(this, (WordCountLine) other, threshold);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final float SIMILARITY_THRESHOLD = 0.75f;

        Path input = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            "Desktop", "lines.txt");
        Line[] lines = Files.lines(input).map(
            s -> new WordCountLine(s))
            .toArray(Line[]::new);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++)
            for (int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
                if (lines[i].isSimilar(lines[j],
                                       SIMILARITY_THRESHOLD))
                    System.out.println(
                        "WARNING! lines " + i + "\n " + lines[i]
                        + "\n and " + j + "\n " + lines[j]
                        + "\n might be the same");
    }
}
```